# Changing identity table names not working in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

**The type or namespace name 'Roles' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'**

I changed Identity table name using below code.(IdentityRoles to Roles) But now I cannot use new name of IdentityRole table . When I use new name it shows me red line under that code.

// Code that i used for rename identity tables

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    static string dbconn = (new ClinicDbContext()).Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(dbconn, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    // Renaming Identity model tables name
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserwithRole");


    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

// This code below has error . I cannot use new name **Roles** instead of **IdentityRole**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addrole(addrole Aroles)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = new Models.ApplicationDbContext();


            context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.**Roles**()
            {
                Name = Aroles.name
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Message = "Role created successfully !";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6NNc.png)

Comment: That code only changes the name of the **table** in the database, not the property name in the `DbContext`.

Comment: Thanks Brendan . you cleared my confusion. And is there any way we can change property name in dbcontext too ?